# How to limit the amount that an integer is increased? c++

Tags: c++

In my game there is a troop quality increasing mechanic, however, I can't figure out how to limit the number of new knights, it just converts all of the militia into knights no matter if the training grounds are built of not, how do I cap it at 50 and 10?

```
           case 3:
                if(training){
                    int newknights =militia;
                    if(newknights>50){
                        newknights = newknights-(newknights%50);
                    }

                    cout<<"With the help of the training grounds you train "<<newknights<<" militia into knights";
                    army+=newknights;
                }
                else{
                         int newknights =militia;
                    cout<<"Without the help of the training grounds you train "<<newknights<<" militia into knights";

                    if(newknights>10){
                        newknights = newknights-(newknights%10);
                    }
                }
                break;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Probably not enough details to give you a real answer: `newknights = newknights-(newknights%50` is not capping `newknights` below 50. You'd want `newknights %= 51` to cap at-or-below 50

Comment: What other details can i add?

Comment: Like what you mean when you say cap at 50 and 10, maybe add an example to reproduce the issue

Comment: I know it's a PITA to do it, but truly a [mcve] helps the most. W/ expected input and expected output. Even better if you can use an online compiler to host your example so that we can jump in and start running it right away.

Comment: Why bother with all the `%` operations? Just `if (newKnights > 50) newKnights = 50;` will surely do the trick. (The `%` approach will fail if `militia` is more than 100; e.g. `101 - 101 % 50 = 100`.)

Comment: You say "newknights = militia" so ... yeah that's what it does. What you need is some unittesting.

Comment: @AdrianMole or even, `int newknights = std::min(militia, 50);`, to keep it on one line. If indeed that's the behaviour he wants.

Comment: @Tommy Indeed!!

Comment: @AdrianMole Thank you, that fixed it.

Comment: Or, if you want to be really 'posh': `newKnights = std::clamp(militia, 0, 50);` (since C++17).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code so that when there are too many militia it just gets set to the number that I want so:

```
case 3:
                case 3:
                if(training){
                    int newknights =militia;
                    if(newknights>50){
                        newknights = 50;
                    }

                    cout<<"With the help of the training grounds you train "<<newknights<<" militia into knights";
                    army+=newknights;
                    militia-=newknights;
                }
                else{
                         int newknights = militia;
                          if(newknights>10){
                        newknights = 10;
                        army+=newknights;
                    militia-=newknights;
                    }
                    cout<<"Without the help of the training grounds you train "<<newknights<<" militia into knights";


                }
                break;
```

And that fixed it.